# Ввод в строку несколько чисел через пробел в Python

Tags: python

```py
class Runner(object):
    def eval(self, string):
        start, goal, days = map(int, string.split())
        i=1
        while start<goal:
            start*=1.1
            i+=1
        if i<days:
            value = True
        else:
            value = False
        return value
    def loop(self):
        line = input("Enter three values: ")
        value = self.eval(line)
        print(value
        if __name__ == '__main__':
        calc = Runner()
        calc.loop()
```

Ввод

```
KeyboardInterrupt
5 10 15
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Это у вас форматирование в вопросе слетело или Вы реально в таком виде код запустить пытаетесь?

Comment: В строке `line = input("Enter three values: ")` уберите `split()`. Вы два раза строку сплитите. Ну и я Вам немного пост поправил, у Вас съехал `__main__`

Comment: @AndyPavlov, Вы напрасно код отформатировали, да конечно то, что вы написали в коментарии тоже было ошибкой но теперь код дает совсем  другое исключение `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` а не то, что указано автором

Comment: @Namerek Вы не убрали `split()` в `line = input("Enter three values: ").split()`. Тогда работает. Написал же, что два раза строка сплитится))) Вернул исходный вариант

Comment: @AndyPavlov, я вам написал о том, что вы верно подметили ошибку. Проблема в том, что та ошибка которую вы указали, дает исключение отличное от того, что указал автор. А Вы отформатировали код

Comment: @Namerek Спасибо) Я воспринял тот код перед правкой, как ошибку форматирования при написании поста. Отсюда и внес правку)

Comment: @AndyPavlov, у самого руки чесались поправить очевидный косяк, но решил уточнить у автора )

Comment: строке line = input("Enter three values: ") убрал split(), но все равно ошибка синтаксиса. Задача в том чтобы числа вводит 5 10 15 с пробелом и без " "

Comment: В Google Colab ваш код работает. А как вы его вообще вызываете? Приведите весь код - вместе с вызовом класса, либо правильно отформатируйте код, как сейчас сделано код класса не вызовется. И приведите полный стек-трейс ошибки, а не только текст самой ошибки. Может питон вообще на что-то другое ругается. Может у вас вообще 2-й питон и он на вызов `print` как функции ругается, например.

Comment: Пробую в IDLE Shell Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information

Comment: Мне нужно выложить в файле только код на проверку https://www.gradescope.com/ Проверка на нем выдает ошибку

Comment: Autograder Results
Test evaluating 4 15 10 (0.0/3.0)
Test Failed: False != 'False'
Test evaluating 4 15 30 (0.0/3.0)
Test Failed: True != 'True'
Test evaluating 10 20 10 (0.0/3.0)
Test Failed: True != 'True'
Test evaluating 3 20 10 (0.0/3.0)
Test Failed: False != 'False'
Test evaluating 5 8 10 (0.0/3.0)
Test Failed: True != 'True'

Comment: Судя по ошибкам тестов может надо строку в кавычках печатать `'True'` или `'False'`, а не просто `True` и `False`? Непонятно как система проверки устроена и что в задании хотят чтобы напечаталось.

Comment: ))) Очешуеть, помогло. Спасибо!!!if i<days:
            value = 'True'
        else:
            value = 'False'

Answer (score 5):

`input_words` - генератор, которые читает из входного потока слова. Он создаётся один раз, используется столько раз, сколько нужно. `take` - выбирает из любого генератора `n` первых значений. Остальное - пример использования:

```
def input_words():
    while True:
        yield from input().split()


def take(g, n):
    yield from (next(g) for _ in range(n))


inp = input_words()
while True:
    print('\nEnter three ints:')
    a, b, c = map(int, take(inp, 3))
    print('The input is', a, b, c)
```

> ```
> $ python input.py
>
> Enter three ints:
> 1 2 3
> The input is 1 2 3
>
> Enter three ints:
> 1 2
> 3
> The input is 1 2 3
>
> Enter three ints:
> 1
> 2
> 3
> The input is 1 2 3
>
> Enter three ints:
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за пример использования from кроме как для импорта.